# Extract data from an onffline MySQL database? (.sql files)

Tags: mysql

Can anyone recommend and utilities to let me view/extract data from a MySQL database that is no longer on a host? I just have the dumped .sql files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to start a local mysqld and import your dump.
Nevertheless it should be possible (but not trivial) to grep out your data from the sql file(s)

Answer (score 1):

another approach would be to create sqlite3 database and import the data there. Python/SQLAlchemy can be of much use.

Answer (score 0):

I installed MySQL in the end and did it that way.

Answer (score -1):

I found [mydumpsplitter](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mydumpsplitter-extract-tables-from-mysql-dump-shell-script) very useful, I even used it to extract tables off a 100GB database. If you have more than one databases in a single dump, you may use the following

```
sed -n '/^-- Current Database: `dbname`/,/^-- Current Database: `/p' fulldump.sql > dbname.sql
```

from [www.rudolfmaduro.com](http://www.rudolfmaduro.com/2010/05/06/extracting-one-database-from-a-full-mysqldump-file/)